# As3 - php - mysql no answer

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I am very new in PHP and MYSQL. I try to read the contents of a database. I have taken over this tutorial but I get back from the server no answer. Is there any security that prevents it?

Tutorial i used: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/load-mysql-data-in-flash-with-as3-and-php

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvnPw.png)

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent

public class App extends MovieClip {
    public static const URL:String = "https://XXX/get.php";

    private var _loader:URLLoader;
    private var _request:URLRequest;

    public function App():void {
        output("constructor");
        loadData();
    }
    private function loadData():void {
        output("loadData");
        var randomParam:String = "?p=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (10000000));
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _request = new URLRequest(URL + randomParam);
        _request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDataFiledToLoad);
        _loader.load(_request);
    }
    public function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
        output("onLoadData result=" + e.target.data);
    }
    private function onDataFiledToLoad(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        output("onDataFiledToLoad error=" + e.text);
    }
    public function output(str:String):void {
        var text:String = field.text;
        field.text = "> " + str + "\n" + text;
    }

}
```

get.php

```
<?php

// defining main variables
$dbHost = "mysqlsvr38.XXX.com";
$dbUser = "sql4449753";
$dbPass = "XXX";
$dbName = "4847554db1";

// connecting and selecting database
@mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($dbName) or die(mysql_error());

// getting data
$data = "";
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    $data .= "\nname=".$row->name.", ";
    $data .= "city=".$row->city;
}
die($data);
```

The answer from the server should look like this

[Server-Answer should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UvuC.png)

But only

[Server-Answer is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHilp.png)

Comment: **Please**, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and `mysql_*` functions have been officially removed in PHP 7. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. If you can't decide, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: You shouldn't use the supression operator (`@`) except at very specific times, for specific reasons, and this is not one of them. It's just bad news.